# verifying and publishing chainlink functions contract giving me error

Tags: chainlink

I am trying to verify and publish my chainlink contract so I can read the response on polygonscan, but I keep running into the error: "Error! Unable to generate Contract Bytecode and ABI (General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode])"

When I compile on Remix, I get no error. I also get no error when deploying. Within remix, I am able to transfer owners and accept owners and everything works. Why can I not verify and publish on polygon scan. I need this to work because I am trying to read the response programmatically.

An example smart contract that I've deployed has the address of: 0x5be7Aa9EcEb50FFB87EB95b144F97c69344F7E8d

The smart contract is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import {FunctionsClient} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/functions/dev/v1_0_0/FunctionsClient.sol";
import {ConfirmedOwner} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import {FunctionsRequest} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/functions/dev/v1_0_0/libraries/FunctionsRequest.sol";

/**
 * @title Chainlink Functions example on-demand consumer contract example
 */
contract FunctionsConsumer is FunctionsClient, ConfirmedOwner {
  using FunctionsRequest for FunctionsRequest.Request;

  bytes32 public donId; // DON ID for the Functions DON to which the requests are sent

  bytes32 public s_lastRequestId;
  bytes public s_lastResponse;
  bytes public s_lastError;

  constructor(address router, bytes32 _donId) FunctionsClient(router) ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
    donId = _donId;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Set the DON ID
   * @param newDonId New DON ID
   */
  function setDonId(bytes32 newDonId) external onlyOwner {
    donId = newDonId;
  }

  /**
   * @notice Triggers an on-demand Functions request using remote encrypted secrets
   * @param source JavaScript source code
   * @param secretsLocation Location of secrets (only Location.Remote & Location.DONHosted are supported)
   * @param encryptedSecretsReference Reference pointing to encrypted secrets
   * @param args String arguments passed into the source code and accessible via the global variable `args`
   * @param bytesArgs Bytes arguments passed into the source code and accessible via the global variable `bytesArgs` as hex strings
   * @param subscriptionId Subscription ID used to pay for request (FunctionsConsumer contract address must first be added to the subscription)
   * @param callbackGasLimit Maximum amount of gas used to call the inherited `handleOracleFulfillment` method
   */
  function sendRequest(
    string calldata source,
    FunctionsRequest.Location secretsLocation,
    bytes calldata encryptedSecretsReference,
    string[] calldata args,
    bytes[] calldata bytesArgs,
    uint64 subscriptionId,
    uint32 callbackGasLimit
  ) external onlyOwner {
    FunctionsRequest.Request memory req; // Struct API reference: https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/api-reference/functions-request
    req.initializeRequest(FunctionsRequest.Location.Inline, FunctionsRequest.CodeLanguage.JavaScript, source);
    req.secretsLocation = secretsLocation;
    req.encryptedSecretsReference = encryptedSecretsReference;
    if (args.length > 0) {
      req.setArgs(args);
    }
    if (bytesArgs.length > 0) {
      req.setBytesArgs(bytesArgs);
    }
    s_lastRequestId = _sendRequest(req.encodeCBOR(), subscriptionId, callbackGasLimit, donId);
  }

  /**
   * @notice Store latest result/error
   * @param requestId The request ID, returned by sendRequest()
   * @param response Aggregated response from the user code
   * @param err Aggregated error from the user code or from the execution pipeline
   * Either response or error parameter will be set, but never both
   */
  function fulfillRequest(bytes32 requestId, bytes memory response, bytes memory err) internal override {
    s_lastResponse = response;
    s_lastError = err;
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you trying to verify this contract? if the contract compiles then its not the contract, but the tool / approach youre using to deploy.  What command creates the "Error! Unable to generate Contract Bytecode and ABI (General Exception, unable to get compiled [bytecode])" issue?

Comment: Did you solve this problem ? I have same error (